# Cache refreshes have caused product display errors

Tags: product, cache

I refreshed both the Layout & Blocks HTML Output caches as they were showing as invalidated. I then added a new product in exactly the same manner as my other products. But, on the front end whilst the new product is present when I click on it to go into that product I just get a box with the product's file path instead of the product's details. Does anyone know how to fix this please ?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have managed to resolve this by clearing the cache on my internet browser. Step one of all issues and I forgot to do it !

Comment: We all have those days....